# SQL input value either single or multiple values

Tags: sql

In `SQL` query if the input value is 0 then take input as all values of the column else consider input value only;

Let's say if the input `city_num = 0` then run the query for all city numbers i.e 1 to 50 else run the query for the input `city_num` say 5.. How to code this?

```
if the City_num = 0 then Select * from emp where City_num in  1to 50
if the City_num = 5 then Select * from emp where City_num = 5
```

;

Comment: HINT:make use of `CASE` statements or use `UNION`

Comment: This is quite vague. Can you provide sample data, expected output, and describe query you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Add this `WHERE` statement:

```
WHERE city_num = ? OR 0 = ?
```

If you pass `0` then it is equivalent to:

```
WHERE city_num = 0 OR 0 = 0
```

and since `0 = 0` is always `TRUE` then it will fetch all the rows. 
If you pass `5` then it is equivalent to:

```
WHERE city_num = 5 OR 0 = 5
```

and since `0 = 5` is always `FALSE` then it will fetch only the row for `city_num = 5`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
DECLARE @input INT = 2;
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE (city_num= @input AND @input > 0) OR @input = 0;
```

I have assumed city_num is integer. Minor fix if varchar

Comment: Forpas has better answer